# Why object detection model is giving different results on different machine

Tags: docker, tensorflow, docker-compose, object-detection, tensorflow-serving

I have trained a hand detection model and export that in tensorflow serving format to serve it in serving.
I have following setup with the versions of different packages and libraries, i am using:

1) Detecting hands using frozen graph

```
versions--
Tensorflow- 1.9.0
numpy 1.16.3 
scipy  0.19 
ternsorflow-server 1.10.0 
opencv - 4.1.0

Results - Bounding box of hands - (86, 169, 186, 161)

Results of Hand Detection Model - Correct
```

2)Detecting hand by hitting the tensorflow server from the local machine

```
versions--
Tensorflow- 1.9.0
numpy 1.16.3
scipy  0.19
ternsorflow-server 1.10.0
opencv  - 3.4.1

Results - Bounding box of hands - (86, 169, 186, 161)
Results of Hand Detection Model - Correct
```

3) Created a Docker image for tensorflow serving and client (flask), now detecting hand by hitting the tensorflow server using POSTMAN on `GPU`

```
versions--
Tensorflow- 1.13.1
numpy 1.16.2
scipy  0.19
ternsorflow-server 1.13.0
opencv version - 3.1.0

Results - Bounding box of hands - (86, 169, 186, 161)
Results of Hand Detection Model - Correct
```

4) Created a Docker image for tensorflow serving and client (flask), now detecting hand by hitting the tensorflow server using POSTMAN on `CPU`

```
Tensorflow- 1.13.1
numpy 1.16.2
scipy  0.19
ternsorflow-server 1.13.0
opencv version - 3.4.1

Results - Bounding box of hands - (137, 204, 124, 205)
Results of Hand Detection Model - Wrong
```

please help me in finding out the reason why i am getting different results on `CPU`.
Please let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19200) might be helpful.

Comment: @VishnuDasu Thanks for the link...
I solved this issue by changing the input image from RGB to BGR format, now it's working.. but still this is a surprise because I trained my model using the images in RGB format.